# Why are some conditions greyed out?

Tags: guild-wars-2

With the release of [Heart of Thorns](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Guild_Wars_2:_Heart_of_Thorns), I've noticed fighting some bosses that sometimes the [condition](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Condition) icons on their hud change from being red to grey.

Here is a poor screen cap from a Youtube video.

[image]

Why do these icons change colour? What significance does this have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's my understanding that this indicates that the target is (or is currently) immune to the effect of the condition in question. However the condition is still *on* the target, for the purposes of applying once their immunity ends or triggering combinations with other effects or skills, et cetera.

This may happen due to the [Resistance](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Resistance) boon, for example (but may possibly also be innate to some creatures).

Comment: In this case, it's due the break-bar being active. All of the greyed-out conditions are soft CC skills, which damage the break-bar over time (in addition to making things proc off them, as you said)

Comment: Weakness is a CC condi? Well I didn't know that.